# JAVA - Help drawing on an extending canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, paint, extends

So, i have a class called MainClass in which extends Canvas. I am trying to let's say draw a filled rectangle on the Canvas without Overriding the paint method. Is there a way to do that or i must override the paint method and put all i want to draw there?

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class MainClass extends Canvas {
    MainClass()
    {
        JFrame MainWindow = new JFrame("Main Window");
        MainWindow.setVisible(true);
        MainWindow.setSize(500, 500);
        MainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MainWindow.add(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MainClass temp = new MainClass();

        Graphics g = (Graphics2D)temp.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        temp.repaint();
    }
}
```

The idea is that i have this class and i can get the graphic object of the canvas and draw on it directly and repaint. Or maybe i was thinking of passing shapes and objects into a method that will do the painting at certain position for me.

Comment: *"Is there a way to do that or i must override the paint method and put all i want to draw there?"* The short answer is no

Comment: The longer answer is, you would need to use a [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html), but this would then require you to take control of the painting process, which just adds to the level of complexity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use a Canvas.
2. Instead extend JPanel
3. And override the JPanel's paintComponent method, not the paint method (and why not override the methods? What is your objection to painting inside of them?).
4. Google the Java Swing painting tutorials and go through them. [Here's the link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).
5. By calling `getGraphics()` on a component, you will obtain a short-lived Graphics context that might work right at that time, but will fail to work if any repaints occur (and these are not under your control), leading to either a program graphics failure or a NullPointerException. You should avoid doing this unless you have dire need and know what you're doing. To "know what you're doing", read the book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) by Haase and Guy.
6. Note that you could always draw directly on a BufferedImage using a Graphics object derived from the image, but then you still should draw the BufferedImage in your `paintComponent(...)` method override.

Comment: I am working on a homework were the skeleton of the code extends Canvas. The reason i want it outside the paint method is because i would like to let's say draw a circle when a specific method is called or a rectangle when a different method is called instead. I don't want to have some crazy flagging and the repaint and have the paint method choose what to draw from the flag.

Comment: @user3689034: Swing graphics are passive, and so your best options are to draw in the paint method or on a BufferedImage (which is still then draw in in a painting method). Note that you can add or remove Shapes in an `ArrayList<Shape>`, and then iterate through the List in your painting method. There are many options here.